# Google Vision Announment - Barcode Scanning Bug

Tags: android, google-vision

We have an app that uses the google bar code scanning API. Recently we have had customers reporting that the barcode scanner in our app (that worked for them previously) is now reporting an error:

"Barcode detection requires that a component be installed from the network. This component is not ready yet, so barcode scanning won't work. Please ensure you are connected to the network and try again later."

We did come across this announcement:

https://developers.google.com/vision/announcement

We aren't sure if this is in fact what is causing the problem as we have several users of the app with the current version of Google Play Services who are still able to use the barcode scanner.

The message language indicates: This will prevent users **who have not already used** Face or Barcode detection from using Face or Barcode scanning.

Q1: Could our existing customers fall into this category if they do something like clear the Google Play Services cache on their device?

Q2: Is there any way to know how long it will take Google to resolve this bug? Our concern is that none of the new installs of this app from the Play Store will work until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately the Mobile Vision API is a fairly opaque system, so not many (if any) users on SO are qualified to answer your questions. Your best bet would be to attempt to reach out to the Mobile Vision API team for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that is reported by your users is indeed related to the bug announcement. Mobile Vision requires certain files (libraries) which will be used for barcode and face detection. These files are not included in the Google Play Services and have to be downloaded separately. There is a special service that downloads the files at app installation time. In some cases the download may be delayed. As noted in the Getting Started guide your app should check the state and react accordingly. If for some reasons it's not possible to download the required files then you cannot use the Mobile Vision API functionality.

The problem is that the service responsible for downloading the files is now disabled due to a serious bug. Thus there is no way to get the necessary files. Unfortunately it means that none of your new users can use the barcode scanning features until the issue is fixed.

The announcement says: "We are working to correct the problem as soon as possible. We expect it will take several weeks to test it thoroughly". It looks like the fix should there in mid to late June. But again nothing is guaranteed of course.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me. My app uses Text Recognition from the Mobile Vision API.

My current **fail-safe mechanism** is:

My app checks if the API is operational (this also triggers necessary missing files to start getting downloaded). If not, I prompt the user that Google Play Services should be updated before using this app (since often this can also be a reason). And then the app takes them to the Google Play Services page on the Play Store. This takes a few seconds usually enough for the missing Vision API components to get installed in the background By the time that the users get back from there to my app, in most cases, the tiny component has been installed. Let me know if you need my code as well.

This is my app for reference: [Optical Dictionary & Vocabulary Teacher.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abdulwasaetariq.odnvt)

Another **work-around** is:

During first-run of your app, show a first-run intro activity, but trigger the Vision API beforehand. During the time that the user is going through your intro sequence, the necessary components will have been installed.

For checking availability, as well as triggering the components to start getting downloaded, use:
`FaceDetector.isOperational()`, `TextRecognizer.isOperational()` or `BarcodeDetector.isOperational()`